# AWS Console Session Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

There is a way to limit the AWS console session timeout to less than 1 hour?

I didn't find any option for this in the console or policy/role in the IAM.
Please assist.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you login to the AWS console? If you are using SAML (a tool like Okta), you need to update the IAM Role timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. there is no way to do it with IAM policy maybe? we are login via the console with IAM credential

Comment: For some weird reason my sessions timeout like this (60 minutes?), it seems by accident and we don't know what's causing it.  I've got to say that this is the most maddening thing ever.  If you do achieve it then those who needs AWS console access day to day will not thank you for this.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using the console and IAM credentials, there is no way to restrict it to less than one hour.

[When does my session expire?](https://aws.amazon.com/console/faqs/#session_expire)

> For security purpose, a login session will **expire in 12 hours** when you
>   sign into the AWS Management Console with your AWS or IAM account
>   credentials. To resume your work after the session expires, we ask you
>   to click the "Click login to continue" button and login again. The
>   duration of federated sessions varies depending on the federation API
>   (GetFederationToken or AssumeRole) and the administrator’s preference.
>   Please go to our Security Blog to learn more about building a secure
>   delegation solution to grant temporary access to your AWS account.

However if you use SAML, then you can restrict it to as low as 15 minutes to as high as 36 hours.

[Creating a URL that Enables Federated Users to Access the AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html)